# Anyone know why and how this works? What will be printed

Tags: c, for-loop, printf

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    for (printf ("3"); printf("2"); printf("1")) break;
return 0;
}
```

Can anyone explain how this works?
Why does it print 32?
When I remove brake it's infinite loop and it prints 12?

Comment: Follow the execution path in a debugger?

Comment: Do you know how a for loop works? Have you read the documentation for printf to see what it returns? There you have the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `printf ("3")` is executed, so it prints `3`. Then `printf("2")` is executed, print `2`. Because `printf()`'s return value is the number of character it prints, which in this case, is `1`, and  because `1` is a nonzero value, the loop continues in the body. The first statement in the body is `break`, meaning to exit out the loop. So the loop terminates. So the result on the screen is `32`

Answer (score 1):

`printf("3")` is called when the for loop initialises.
`printf("2")` is called to see if the loop iteration should terminate.

printf() returns the number of characters it prints, which is 1 in both cases, so the loop decides to execute.

The loop body is simply `break`, so the loop terminates at that point, and the program ends.